# SKSpriteNode zrotation M_PI is infuriating

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

so all i want to do is rotate an `SKSPriteNode` by 90 degrees. just that. It should be simple yet my first approach, assuming it would be degrees, turns the object in completely the wrong diection. so i head to google > stackoverflow. plenty of answers to do with this, okay so ill try using `M_PI` or some variation. nope. 'Double' is not convertible to 'CGFloat'. google again. "Try using skaction with blah blah" nope.

how difficult can it be to rotate a sprite? or am i insane

Comment: As a software developer, you must have patience and keep a cool head in all situations. If you can't do that, it would be better to look for a different job.

Comment: All you need to know: is zRotation in radians (it is) or degrees? Do positive values rotate counterclockwise (they do) or clockwise? This info is found in the Sprite Kit class reference. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/zRotation The rest are separate issues, and the fact that you're frustrated doesn't help bringing things together. As a side note, if you consider this kind of rotation frustrating, don't try Unity with its mix of 2D/3D, rotation over time, Quaternions and various Rotate functions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's a rant, not a question.

Comment: Its been awhile since high school, but I'm pretty sure 90 degrees is M_PI_2

Comment: Despite your rant, someone was kind enough to provide an answer that (it appears) helped you out.  If you want this question to remain open and help others with a similar problem, I'd suggest retitling it (e.g. "How to rotate SKSpriteNode 90 degrees using Swift") and show the code that you originally tried that gave you the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Swift based on your "'Double' is not convertible..." comment.

The following rotates a sprite 90 degree counterclockwise:

```
sprite.runAction(SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: 1.0))
```

The following rotates a sprite 90 degree clockwise:

```
sprite.runAction(SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(-M_PI_2), duration: 1.0))
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work fine for me. Understanding conversions between radians and degrees is important.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Conversion_between_radians_and_degrees

sprite.zRotation = CGFloat(M_PI_2)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to create an extension for Int:

```
extension Int
{
    var deg2Rad : CGFloat
    {
        return CGFloat(self) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
sprite.runAction(SKAction.rotateByAngle(180.deg2Rad, duration: 1.0))
```

Makes it more human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

`let threesixty:CGFloat = 360 * .pi / 180`